# Why does an implementation of an algorithmic problem not work?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

The question is to find the number of islands. https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/

Solution 1:

```
class Solution:    
    def dfs(self, row, column, grid):
        if row < 0 or column < 0 or row>= len(grid) or column >= len(grid[0]):
            return 0
        if grid[row][column] == '0':
            return 0
        grid[row][column] = '0'                    
        self.dfs(row+1, column, grid)
        self.dfs(row-1, column, grid)
        self.dfs(row, column+1, grid)
        self.dfs(row, column-1, grid)
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        count = 0
        for row in range(len(grid)):
            for column in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[row][column] == '1':
                    self.dfs(row, column, grid)
                    count += 1

        return count
```

Solution 2(Doesn't work)

```
class Solution:
    def dfs(self, row, column, grid):
        if row < 0 or column < 0 or row>= len(grid) or column >= len(grid[0]):
            return 0
        if grid[row][column] == '0':
            return 0
        grid[row][column] = '0'                    
        for i in range(-1, 2):
            for j in range(-1, 2):
                if i!=0 or j!=0:
                    self.dfs(row+i, column+j, grid)

    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        count = 0
        for row in range(len(grid)):
            for column in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[row][column] == '1':
                    self.dfs(row, column, grid)
                    count += 1
        return count
```

Can anyone please explain why 2 doesn't work. 
I'm running a loop in which every statement gives a recursive call.

But this logic works in Java, why?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4Nh-EgWjyQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code also consider diagonals as valid. This is why it differs from the first one.

```
11000
11000
00100
00011
```

Both are valid codes but they do not answer the same question. The above input, first will return 1 and second 3.

Comment: Yes, didn't see that. Thanks!